# Determine the Moose Type for providing conversion to JSON

Tags: json, perl, introspection, moose

I have a class, MyClass:

```
package MyClass;
use Moose;

has 'IntegerMember' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Int'
);

has 'BooleanMember' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Bool'
);

sub TO_JSON {
    my $self = shift;
    return { % { $self } };
}
```

Currently when I instantiate MyClass and pass the new object to the json_encoder I get a JSON string returned as expected.  I was hoping that the perl booleans ( 1,0 ) would be converted to ( true, false ) but that is not how the JSON module is designed:

```
use JSON;
use MyClass;

my $object_to_encode = MyClass->new ( 
    IntegerMember => 10,
    BooleanMember => 1
);
my $json_encoder = JSON->new->convert_blessed;
my $json_data = $json_encoder->encode( $object_to_encode );
```

In MyClass, I want to improve my TO_JSON subroutine to provide a conversion of any Moose 'Bool' member from ( 1 or 0 ) to ( true or false ):

```
sub TO_JSON {
    my $self = shift;
    for my $member ( %$self ) {
        if {
            # Convert '1' to 'true' if Moose Type is 'Bool'
        } else {
            # Keep the member as is
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I determine the Moose Type** as I iterate through MyClass' members so I can provide a mechanism for the conversion?

Comment: The JSON module represents _true_ and _false_ as scalar references `\1` and `\0`. But it doesn't know if a `1` or a `2` is a boolean.

Comment: You need to call `$json_encoder->encode`. It's an object.

Comment: Also, that's not what the _isa_ in Moose does. It does not really care about the _type_ as such, as there are no types in Perl (or Moose). The thing you put in _isa_ is only used for runtime-checking things you put into an attribute.

Comment: And you should not meddle with the internals of the underlying `$self` directly. In fact, your `for` loop will only iterate once, as `$self` is a hash reference. So you have a list of one element. That element is `$self`. It will be assigned to `$member`, and then you're done. But there's also the syntax error, because `for` blocks cannot have an `else` block. I think you need to rethink what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks simbabque .  I have made corrections to syntax errors you mentioned that I overlooked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
package MyClass;
use Moose;

has 'IntegerMember' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Int'
);

has 'BooleanMember' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Bool'
);

sub TO_JSON {
    my $self = shift;
    my $meta = $self->meta;
    my $result = {};
    for my $attr ($meta->get_all_attributes) {
        my $name = $attr->name;
        my $value = $attr->get_value($self);
        my $type = $attr->type_constraint;
        if ($type && $type->equals('Bool')) {
            $value = $value ? \1 : \ 0;
        }
        $result->{$name} = $value;
    }
    return $result;
}

1
```

We use the [metaclass object](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Meta::Class) (accessible via `->meta`) to introspect the class and get a list of all attributes (in the form of [meta-attribute objects](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Meta::Attribute)).

For each attribute, we get the name, current value, and [type constraint](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint) (if any). If the type is `Bool`, we convert the value to either `\1` or `\0`. The JSON module understands these values and converts them to `true` or `false`.

And a test program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::MaybeXS;
use MyClass;

my $object_to_encode = MyClass->new ( 
    IntegerMember => 10,
    BooleanMember => 1
);
my $json_encoder = JSON->new->convert_blessed;
my $json_data = $json_encoder->encode( $object_to_encode );

print "Result: $json_data\n";
```

Output:

```
Result: {"IntegerMember":10,"BooleanMember":true}
```